# Communicate to a remote server over internet

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to develop an winform application which will communicate with a remote server. The server will have a real IP. Each client will send and receive data over internet. Client application is object-oriented and all business objects will execute in server.

I have heard about .net remoting and socket programming. I don't know which one is the best way for this purpose.

Should i use .net remoting for my application?

Comment: What is the protocol for communication on the remote server?

Comment: You shall provide your requirements. (Firewalls in between? NAT? Any other middleware used?)

Comment: If I were you, I would look into web services, and specifically the WCF framework.

Comment: And, btw a guideline is what you won't get.

Comment: @ryadavilli, i am not too much familiar with protocol. But i will connect through a dial-up internet connection via GSM modem.

Comment: Which O/S, web server, or service is running on the remote server? Will you be writing the server-side code? Will it too be .NET software?

Comment: @Klaus Byskov Hoffmann, isn't there any way to do it in c# winform application? I don't know WCF.

Comment: @ ChrisW, windows server running sql server 2008.

Comment: You can use WCF in a winforms application. WCF is not a separate language, it is just a framework that makes it easy to, well, communicate over the network.

Comment: @ Klaus Byskov Hoffmann- Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WCF

[Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx)